# How would you ask ''are you there ?'' on social media?

Tags: phrases

I have a Japanese friend whom I chat to from time to time on a software called Line.

Let's say their name is Haruto.

Sometimes I like to start by saying something like ''Haruto san, are you there ?''.

How would you say that in Japanese ?

I found the following phrases online but I have no idea what kind of nuance they carry. I'm just looking for a casual friend-to-friend way of expressing it.

Haruto san, soko ni imasu ka ?

Haruto san, iru ?

Comment: You answered your question.

Comment: Are both those expression exactly the same in their usage and nuance in this context ?

Comment: @Kantura "soko ni" won't be needed if you have no intention to contrast to another place, and vice versa.

Comment: @broccolifacemask-cloth So can I just type ''imasu ka?'' ?

Comment: @Kantura If you just want to know if they're at the keyboard.

Comment: Not everyone is gonna read the comments so maybe you could explicitly post an answer @user4092.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As answered originally in the comments section of the question:

> はるとさん、いますか。
> Haruto san, imasu ka ?
>
> はるとさん、いる？
> Haruto san, iru ?

Are two expressions that can be used. Please see the [comments section](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/78433/how-would-you-ask-are-you-there-on-social-media#comment128400_78433) for the discussion regarding their differences.